# How to Calculate the highest text frequency by column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr, data-wrangling

I have a data like this:

[image]

how to change become:

[image]

I need some helps to fit it...

Comment: What's the logic behind entries in column `X3`? Is this the median value? If so, an option is `df %>% group_by(X1) %>% summarise(X2 = toString(X2), X3 = median(X2))`.

Comment: the highest text frequency in X2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` option

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(X1) %>%
    summarise(
        X3 = names(sort(table(X2), decreasing = TRUE))[1],
        X2 = toString(X2),
        .groups = "drop") %>%
    select(X1, X2, X3)
## A tibble: 3 × 3
#  X1    X2                        X3    
#  <chr> <chr>                     <chr> 
#1 A     high, high                high  
#2 B     middle, middle, high      middle
#3 C     low, middle, middle, high middle
```

Note: Since you're overwriting `X2`, we need to carry out the calculation for `X3` first and then summarise `X2`. The last `select` call reorders columns to match your expected output.

Note also that this might need some careful checking of edge cases on your side to deal with ties in word frequencies.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- data.frame(
    X1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
    X2 = c("high", "high", "middle", "middle", "high", "low", "middle", "middle", "high"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *base*, group by *X1*, collapse the strings - *toString*, and get the most frequent string - *table*:

```
aggregate(X2 ~ X1, df, function(i) c(toString(i), names(sort(-table(i)))[ 1 ]))
#   X1                      X2.1   X2.2
# 1  A                high, high   high
# 2  B      middle, middle, high middle
# 3  C low, middle, middle, high middle
```